# Access all symbols in a *.swf file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there a way to access all **exported symbols** in a *.swf file?

I mean all the symbols that are marked *Export to Actionscript* in the Library of **Flash IDE**. That way I could use **getDefinition()** class without having to know the name of the symbol beforehand.

This is for an internal tool made in AS3 that will work along a framework, which needs to perform some operations on every symbol of a ***.swf** file.
So performance isn't required, and a hackish solution (accessing ByteArray of the swf or something like that) is valid.

Thanks

---

As **Daniel** suggested, I ended up using [as3swf](https://github.com/claus/as3swf) to parse the ByteCode of the *.swf file and read the class.

Here's a simple function I made that returns an array containing the symbol names, ready to be used with **getDefinition()**. You must pass in a **ByteArray** of the ***.swf** file.

```
    private function getSymbolList(bytes:ByteArray):Array {
        var swf:SWF = new SWF(bytes);
        var ret:Array = [];
        for each(var tag:ITag in swf.tags) {
            if(tag is TagSymbolClass) {
                var symbolClass:TagSymbolClass = tag as TagSymbolClass;
                for (var i:int = 0; i < symbolClass.symbols.length; i++) {
                    ret.push(symbolClass.symbols[i].name);
                } return ret;
            }
        } return ret;
    }
```

---

With the new **11.3 Flash API**, this feature is built-in.

```
var definitions:Vector.<String> =
    this.loaderInfo.applicationDomain.getQualifiedDefinitionNames();
```

Comment: Do you think a swf decompiler would suite your needs?

Comment: If the decompiler can be invoked from my tool (which is a swf file) and will return a list with the names of the symbols from an external swf, then yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible by reading the bytecode of the swf, de-serializing it and reading the class names.

This is complicated work though, so it's best to look to low level libraries that already do that. the as3commons bytecode class does this.

http://www.google.com/codesearch#Ueq88nAe-j0/trunk/as3-commons-bytecode/

[as3swf](https://github.com/claus/as3swf) can also get at this data. you can have a look through the classes and see how they do it, or just use the classes.

I haven't actually used them, so I don't have any code to share, but hope this helps.

Comment: Seems like it is what I was looking for, I'm currently looking into it.

Comment: It was really simple. I updated the question with the function I made. Thanks for your help.